# Send data(Client_id=1,Staff_id=2) from android application to tomcat server

Tags: java, android, android-service

i want to send data from android application to tomcat java server.
Data is just one is client_id which is 1 and second is staff_id which is 2.
after authenticate the client id and staff id from tomcat show me a toast of success....please help...

Code is here

```
public class MyAsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // display a progress dialog for good user experiance
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // implement API in background and store the response in current         variable
    String current = "";
    try {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.13:8080/digitaldisplay/s/m/data");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                current += (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
            // return the data to onPostExecute method
            return current;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    }
    return current;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("data", s.toString());
    // dismiss the progress dialog after receiving data from API
    try {
        // JSON Parsing of data
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);

        JSONObject oneObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        // Pulling items from the array
        client = Integer.parseInt(oneObject.getString("client"));
        staff = Integer.parseInt(oneObject.getString("staff"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   } }}
```

Comment: Look into using `HttpURLConnection`, or the HTTPS version of that if your Tomcat has an SSL cert which your app recognizes.

Comment: no version is there server side code is completed by server..which is on java EE...and i receive from server just a server local url with ip like  http://192.68.1.1:8080/display/data.

Comment: You're not listening to what I am telling you.  I have built Android apps before which use a J2EE server, and the standard way of talking to them is via `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: my tomcat has no an SSL cert...

Comment: It doesn't need it.  You only need that if you plan to use HTTPS (which you should be using when you actually launch your app).

Comment: Actually i m not working on Tomcat i m just work on android on the front end....and he gave me just a localhost address which i told u...and i work on it with asynctask and JSON but its failed

Comment: Telling me that it failed provides zero help here.  Add your async code, highlight where the REST call is being made, and include the relevant portion of the stack trace.

Comment: i uploaded....see

Comment: Thanks.  I don't use your style of code when making Android REST calls.  How far does the code get?  Also, are you trying to hit a GET or POST service?  There is a default being used here (I can't remember which), but it might be the wrong one.

Comment: can u give me code example...??

Comment: thnx...m waiting....

Comment: By the way, your URL looks off.  It looks like it's localhost or another local computer.  Check to make sure it's right.

Comment: yeah...i know this URL localhost...i m trying this code just for testing and i m testing on local computer....its local tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code looks off to me.  This is the pattern I usually follow when making a REST call from an activity using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
try {
    String endpoint = "http://192.168.1.13:8080/digitaldisplay/s/m/data";
    URL obj = new URL(endpoint);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");    // but maybe you want GET here...
    con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    JSONObject inputJSON = new JSONObject();
    inputJSON.put("Client_id", 1);
    inputJSON.put("Staff_id", 2);

    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(inputJSON.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
    // handle timeout exception
    responseCode = -1;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle general exception
    responseCode = 0;
}
```

The only major change in adapting the above code for GET would be that you wouldn't write your input data to the connection.  Instead, you would just append query parameters to the URL.  I am possibly guessing that you need POST here, since your URL doesn't have any query parameters in it.